SQL (Snowflake) forward looking event date attribution
I have the following table with these constraints -

Units can only be released or bought on a given day (one of the columns will always be 0)
Units released on one day can be bought from the next day onwards
Units released on one day can be bought in parts across multiple days (need not be fully bought on one day)




Event Date
Released Units
Bought Units




1/1/2024
1
0


1/2/2024
0
0.5


1/3/2024
0.5
0


1/4/2024
0
1


1/5/2024
0.5
0


1/6/2024
0.5
0


1/7/2024
0
1



I would now like to understand when a given "released unit" was fully bought. I am working on SQL in Snowflake.
For the above example, I'd like the following output to be as shown:



Event Date
Released Units
Units fully bought by




1/1/2024
1
1/4/2024


1/2/2024
0
NULL


1/3/2024
0.5
1/4/2024


1/4/2024
0
NULL


1/5/2024
0.5
1/7/2024


1/6/2024
0.5
1/7/2024


1/7/2024
0
NULL



Appreciate the help!
The first_value function wouldn't work here as it can attribute one Bought to many Released, Im not sure how to knock one Bought out as soon as it is attributed to a Release
Example 2 - Customers can buy more than what is released (our business allows for oversold situations):



Event Date
Released Units
Bought Units




1/1/2024
0.5
0


1/2/2024
0.5
0


1/3/2024
0
0.5


1/4/2024
0
1


1/5/2024
0.5
0


1/6/2024
0.5
0


1/7/2024
0
1.5



For the above example, the output would be as shown:



Event Date
Released Units
Units fully bought by




1/1/2024
0.5
1/3/2024


1/2/2024
0.5
1/4/2024


1/3/2024
0
NULL


1/4/2024
0
NULL


1/5/2024
0.5
1/7/2024


1/6/2024
0.5
1/7/2024


1/7/2024
0
NULL




This is a great asof join use-case.  Here's the sample code that works for the scenario you've provided:
with data (event_date, released_units, bought_units) as (
    select *
    from (values 
      ('1/1/2024'::date,1,0),
      ('1/2/2024'::date,0,0.5),
      ('1/3/2024'::date,0.5,0),
      ('1/4/2024'::date,0,1),
      ('1/5/2024'::date,0.5,0),
      ('1/6/2024'::date,0.5,0),
      ('1/7/2024'::date,0,1)
    )
), running as (
    select *
         , sum(released_units - bought_units) over (order by event_date) as run_total
    from data
    qualify run_total <= 0
)
select d.event_date
     , d.released_units
     , case when d.released_units > 0 then r.event_date else null end as fully_bought_by
from data d
asof join running r
match_condition(d.event_date<r.event_date)
order by d.event_date;

The data CTE is just to get your sample data into the query.
The running CTE then does a sum over the events to determine every point when the inventory hits zero (which is what the qualify does).
Then, the magic begins.  Leveraging asof join allows you to get the first zero-inventory date that is greater than when the inventory was released.
Results of the above query match your expected output.

Hi Mike, thanks for the response! The query works for the situation where 'released - bought' aka inventory hits zero. However, our business allows for overall bought to be greater than released, leading to oversold situations for which we have other coping strategies. Apologies for not giving more examples from the get go! See example 2 I've added to the main question. The query wouldn't work in those cases where cumulative bought > released. Any ideas on how I can by-pass the inventory hits zero condition and keep leveraging the asof logic ?

Without testing the new scenario directly, you could try to use qualify run_total <= 0 and see if that works.  I would think it'd fit your situation, still.

Although, I have to ask.  In cases where bought > released, does the next release "make up" for that difference, or is the next day's release considered available inventory?  Depending on the answer, we might want to force ZERO values when the number goes negative to make sure the running sum is working correctly.
